# a2oj shows wrong answer to my submission for 193.?

Tags: c

Does anyone know why does this program give wrong output? I tried all the test cases I can think of but it seems that there are some test cases that I don't cover. Here is the link: http://a2oj.com/p.jsp?ID=193

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int t, i;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        char str[100];
        scanf("%s", str);
        int l=strlen(str),j, c[26]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        for(j=0;j<l;j++)
        {
            int k;
            for(k=97;k<=122;k++)
            {
                if((int)str[j]==k)
                    c[k-97]++;
            }
        }
        int max=c[0], m, maxi=0;
        for(m=0;m<26;m++)
        {
            if(c[m]>max)
            {
                max=c[m];
                maxi=m;
            }
        }
        printf("%d %c\n", max, maxi+97);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What the program does and what's the expected right output?

Comment: It asks for no. of test casesafter that, 
It takes input of strings of small alphabets of max.100
Output should print the no. of max. no. of used alphabet followed by that alphabet.
Sample Input:
3
abac
abc
zzz


Sample Output:
2 a
1 a
3 z

Comment: Still not clear what are you trying to do

Comment: Hope now u can @fluter ... it's edited now.

Comment: How should we know what the correct output is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is your `char str[100];` which can't hold a string with 100 letters.

Try:

```
char str[101];
```